# Is it possible to record and play audio in iPhone simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios, ios-simulator

Is it possible to record and play audio in iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I have tested my application that does that using the simulator.

Comment: I have working code, but I do not get audio recording or playback from the simulator.  Is there a trick or restriction?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder where you tested your application? Directly from Apple  Docs.

Directly from Apple Doc.

Hardware Limitations
While most of the functionality of iOS devices can be simulated in iOS Simulator, there are some hardware features that must be tested directly on a device. The hardware features that cannot be simulated are:

Motion Support

Accelerometer

Gyroscope

Audio and Video Input

Camera

Microphone

Proximity Sensor

To test your app on a device, you must be a member of the iOS Developer Program. To learn more about enrolling in the iOS Developer Program, see Managing Accounts in App Distribution Guide.